# accessing current rowData of dataprovider in flex view

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a view

```
                    <view:SampleDataGridView
                        rowCount="{Math.min(MAX_ROW_COUNT, hostComponent.dataList.length)}"
                        dataprovider="{hostComponent.dataList}"
                        buttonMode="true"
                        click="clickRow(event)"
                    />
```

I want to get which row was clicked. I tried using `currentTarget` and `target` from `event` object however it wasn't of much use.

Is there a way I can pass some parameter in `clickEvent` function like `clickEvent(rowData)` or `clickEvent(currentRowIndex)`?

Is there any property when we use `dataProvider` to show `currentIndex`?

Comment: `verticleScrollPosition` can be one option. I can see `verticletScrollPosition` in debugger mode. Do I need to cast `event.target` to somevalue so that I can access `verticleScrollPosition`.

Comment: use a custom renderer.

Comment: If the SampleDataGridView extends Datagrid, there are selectedItem and selectedIndex properties in the Datagrid that you can read after a click

Answer (score 0):

**Data Grid**

```
 <mx:DataGrid id="employeeDataGrid" doubleClickEnabled="true" itemDoubleClick="selectEmployee(event);" dataProvider={employeeList} >
```

**Handler**

```
protected function selectEmployee(event:ListEvent):void
{
    var selectedEmployee:Employee = event.currentTarget.selectedItem as Employee;
}
```

Comment: this works when the view component is `mx:DataGrid` but not with `SampleDataGridView` that I am having.